How do i modify this circuit so that it gives a dc output of -5V/+5V
Thats the picture of the diagram
And that's the picture of what I have done so I have tried using the LM7805 and the LM7905 but I am getting it wrong


The LM7805 and 7905 are very different from the LM317 and LM337. They are not drop-in replacements. For one, they have different pinouts and the LM317 and 337 are adjustable while the 7805/7905 are fixed voltage. Have you consulted the datasheets for these components? For example, the resistors and pots that are used with the LM317 and 337 are not needed for the 7805/7905.

And no matter what, that bread board rat's nest needs to be remade from scratch, there is nowhere something like that is acceptable, including student exercises. Wires up in the air, too long wires, wires needlessly crossing each other, using breadboards in the first place... all of it cardinal sins. And with caps that large, also plain dangerous. Learning through-hole soldering is pretty easy and will give you so much better results.

solderless breadboard are not suitable places to build voltage regulator circuits

Left of, and including, C1,C2,Cb,Cb  all of that is good.
For the rest.
Build the simplest example circuits in the 7805 and 7905 data sheets.
Use soldered connections not solderless breadboard.
Solder because one slip and breadboard a regulator can suddenly stop
regulating and deliver full voltage, that can break what's on the receiving end.
You will probably need heatsinks on the 7x05 ICs.
